# Proofs and ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $\dot{x} = \frac{x}{x^2 + t^2 + 1}$, $t, x \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Prove that  $\exists \epsilon > 0$ and if $|x_0|  < \epsilon $ and $\phi : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to

$$\dot{x} = f(x)$$

When $x(0) = x_0$, then  $| \phi(t) | < 10^{-4}, \forall t \in [0, 1000]$

Comment: What is $f(x)$? What is $I$? Do you know about the continuous dependence of the solution on the initial condition? Then compare here with the zero-solution.